# Determine which object changed realm notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Realm allows us to watch for changes in our data. However, it does not seem trivial to me to determine which object in the results array changed. How can we do this efficiently?

```
// Observe RLMResults Notifications
token = [[Person objectsWhere:@"age > 5"] addNotificationBlock:^(RLMResults<Person *> *results, NSError *error) {
    // results is identical to '[Person objectsWhere:@"age > 5"]'
    [myViewController updateUI];
}];

// later
[token stop];
```

These seems especially difficult since I can't keep a reference to the hold results since it gets updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Realm does not currently have fine-grained notifications. However, the feature is now submitted pull request and under the review. If this pull request is merged, you can determine what objects are updated/inserted/deleted.

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3359